# Button gets an incorrect PHP value by default via javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following selector with options:

```
<select name="" id="product-selector" class="list_item">
    <?php

    if( have_rows('section_a') ):
    while( have_rows('section_a') ): the_row();
    if( have_rows('product_item') ):
    while( have_rows('product_item') ): the_row();

    $product_item_quantity = get_sub_field('product_item_quantity');
    $product_item_price = get_sub_field('product_item_price');
    $product_item_id = get_sub_field('product_item_id');
    $product_item_variation_id = get_sub_field('product_item_variation_id');
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>" data-content="<?php echo $product_item_quantity; ?> <span class='price' data-count='<?php echo $product_item_quantity; ?>' data-price='<?php echo $product_item_price; ?>'><?php echo $product_item_price; ?>"> </option>
    <?php endwhile; endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
</select>
```

And I have the following button:

```
<div class="submit">
<a class="btn btn-warning" id="purchase" href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo $product_item_id; ?>&variation_id=<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>">Order Now</a>
</div>
```

My javascript is:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("product-selector").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("purchase").href = "?add-to-cart="+"<?php echo $product_item_id; ?>"+"&"+"variation_id="+this.value+"/";
}
</script>
```

When user click by the Order button the link changes dynamically - it gets the value of  and should get the `<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>"` via the `"variation_id="+this.value+"` and it works fine, but when the page loads, the `<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>` value of the button get the LAST option value, but not a first (default) one.

Much appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you share the code where `$product_item_variation_id` is set?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should make a variable to save the first value. Because you already loop. so default value is last value of the select.

```
<?php $product_item_variation_id_first = ""; ?>
<select name="" id="product-selector" class="list_item">
    <?php

    if( have_rows('section_a') ):
    while( have_rows('section_a') ): the_row();
    if( have_rows('product_item') ):
    while( have_rows('product_item') ): the_row();

    $product_item_quantity = get_sub_field('product_item_quantity');
    $product_item_price = get_sub_field('product_item_price');
    $product_item_id = get_sub_field('product_item_id');
    $product_item_variation_id = get_sub_field('product_item_variation_id');
    if ($product_item_variation_id_first == "")
        $product_item_variation_id_first = $product_item_variation_id;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $product_item_variation_id; ?>" data-content="<?php echo $product_item_quantity; ?> <span class='price' data-count='<?php echo $product_item_quantity; ?>' data-price='<?php echo $product_item_price; ?>'><?php echo $product_item_price; ?>"> </option>
    <?php endwhile; endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
</select>

<div class="submit">
<a class="btn btn-warning" id="purchase" href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo $product_item_id; ?>&variation_id=<?php echo $product_item_variation_id_first; ?>">Order Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: please let me know the result. I will be online in 30 mins.

Comment: Just started adding the variable and can't get how it would be better to add it. I use ACF PRO for this solution as you can see. I don't think that it's a good idea to place the new var in the repeater. Please, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: If you think that it's not good, we can use the javascript. When page is loaded, we can trigger the dropdown.